# $V$-$I$ linear OR $V=IR$ is statement of Ohm's law?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

What is the real statement of [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law): $V$-$I$ is linear OR $V=IR$?

Looks like V-I is linear is ohm's law and conductors don't alway obey ohm's law
and R=V/I is a general definition of R wheather conductor obeys ohm's law or not

Can someone please confirm above.

Comment: [Static and differential resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance#Static_and_differential_resistance)

Answer (score 3):

I confirm your statement (with the slight amendment that for Ohm's law the relationship is not just linear but proportional (as *I* = 0 when *V* =0)).

A trickier issue is whether Ohm's law states that...

**for a conductor *I* is proportional to *V***, in which case the law has a lot of exceptions, because there are lots of non-linear conductors (e.g. silicon diodes),

OR that **for homogeneous conductors (e.g. wires made of one metal) at constant temperature (and, strictly, constant pressure), *I* is proportional to *V***. In this case the law is obeyed pretty accurately with no exceptions except at very high currents, as far as I know.

I won't give an opinion on which is the better statement of Ohm's law, because I once got into a lot of trouble over the issue.

The equation $R=\frac{V}{I}$ defines resistance, $R$. The equation *by itself* doesn't tell us anything about how a conductor behaves. We can apply the equation to a silicon diode, for example, finding that (within a certain range of pds) the diode's resistance drops from immeasurably high to a lower and lower value as we increase the forward pd, *V*. The key thing about an *ohmic* conductor is that the resistance, as defined above, *doesn't* change as we change the applied pd.

Comment: thx this is helpful. Just to make sure I am getting the distinction between I proportional to V and V=IR. 1st one says R is indepedant of V & I and 2nd one says R may depend on V and/or I and but at any time R=V/I is that fair.? and I think even V=IR is not always true. is that correct .?

Comment: Yes, that's it, though I'd argue with the bit after your last 'and'. The way I look at it is that $R=\frac{V}{I}$ defines $R$. So it's always right, (for the same reason that a bachelor is always an unmarried male) and can be applied to both ohmic and non-ohmic conductors. But for Ohmic conductors, $R$ is a constant.